# How can I achieve a component across every screen that can be updated by the current screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

Hi I'm looking to have a modal (likely react-native-modalize) that is visible on every screen, but can adapt based on what screen is currently showing.

I don't want to introduce redux or anything like that. I don't think it's a tab navigation issue either, as this is a modal that starts out at only around 100 pixels but can open to almost full screen.

I have the modal as a component like this:

```
 <QuickAccess {...props} />
```

And currently I call it on screens, but it's not an immediate render/doesn't seem to be a core part of the app as it just sort of... shows up.

[image]

Any thoughts would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `Modal` and just render it on your root screen navigator like below and store its reference globally on your utility class and can show it anywhere in the app on any screen.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <MainScreen />
    <YourModal ref={(ref) => Utility.setModalRef(ref)} />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Hi Nooruddun, you can just store a variable in a utility class? i was under the impression a class could not story anything and each time you call it would be a different version of that class (without the variable)?

Comment: How would that Utility function look such that it can be called from anywhere and maintain that reference?

Comment: @DanFein Yes It would be a utility class stores global reference which can  call on any class or screen anywhere

Comment: Is there anything that makes something a utility class that's different from another class? I can't see anything other than helper functions when I google it. It's not clear how it would be referenceable and wouldn't just create a separate variable when each screen calls it.